# Dynamic dictionary keys in DJango table

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am absolutely new to Django need help. I have a dynamic list of dictionaries which I want to display in django table.

```
[{'index': 'Price', 'Price': 1.0}, {'index': 'Sale', 'Price': 1.0}, {'index': 'Reviews', 'Price': -1.0}]
```

"index" key will remain constant but second key is dynamic. I want to show this data in a table. I can show the value of first key but cant figure out how to show the value of dynamic key.

My django template code is as below

```
 <div class="container fluid">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <h2 class="text-center">Correlation with {{var}}</u></h2><br>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Index</th>
                        <th>Score</th>
                        

                    </tr>
                    {% for var in variable %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{var.index}}</td>
                        <td>{{var.{{input}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </thead>
                </tbable>
        </div>
```

Views.py

```
def corelation(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        var_input = request.POST.get('variable')
        data = {'Price':[23, 65], 'Sale':[76, 82], 'Reviews':[52, 34]}
        df = pd.dataframe(data)
        corr = df.corr()
        var_corr = corr[var_input].sort_values(ascending = False)

        
        #this is for showing item wise correlation() fucntion
        json_varCorr = var_corr.reset_index().to_json(orient ='records')
        data_varCorr = []
        data_varCorr = json.loads(json_varCorr)

        context = {'variable': data_varCorr,
                    'input':var_input,
        }
        
        return render(request, 'variable.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

```
<div class="container fluid">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <h2 class="text-center">Correlation with {{input}}</u></h2><br>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Index</th>
                        <th>Score</th>
                    
                    </tr>
                    {% for var in variable %}
                    <tr>
                    {% for key,val in var.items %}
                        <td>{{val}}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    
                </thead>
                </tbable>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your variable to be :

```
variable = [{'index': 'Price', 'Price': 1.0}, {'index': 'Sale', 'Price': 1.0}, {'index': 'Reviews', 'Price': -1.0}]
```

To get the keys and its value you can do something like this in templates:

```
{% for var in variable %}
  {% for key, val in var.items %}
    <p>{{key}} - {{val}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: where to put this code bro? will this be in views,py or templates?

Comment: need value of second key